# Objective-C invalid variables values as a double

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdate

I have the following piece of code...

```
double time = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
double startTime = time;
double endTime = time;
```

When I run the code, the `startTime` and `endTime` are not even close to each other. For example, the `startTime` is `4378480` and the `endTime` is `1883506224`.

Why is there such a difference between the 2 time values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you link the code you are using to output the values, remember you need to use %f not %d in the formatter. The above should be equivalent as both are pointing to the same value

Answer (score 3):

First, use `NSTimeInterval`, not `double`, for all the variable types.

Next -- show the code you are using to print the values.   I suspect you are using the wrong format for the variable type (as time intervals always have a decimal component) and are effectively printing garbage as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, the problem I was having was using the incorrect NSLog character.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startTime]
```

When it was supposed to be this.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", startTime]
```

Comment: If you are curious as to why you got those wrong values; integers are 4 bytes and doubles are 8.  More likely than not, if you were to print "%d %d %d %d", startTime, endTime, you'd see the two numbers repeated.